# Django submit a form->redirect to a new page->auto update new page

Tags: javascript, html, django

Ok as the title describes, Im trying to create a webpage(test.html) where in after the form is submitted it should redirect me to a new page(say status.html).And after this page loads It should shows some continuous updates on the submitted task. I was able to accomplish this on a single page , when Im trying to redirect this to a new page Im out of luck.

test.html

```
<form action="status/" method="POST" id="start-form">
.....
<input type="submit" value="Start" class="tbutton">
```

views.py

```
def status_page(request):
print("Inside redirect")
return HttpResponseRedirect(request,'my_app/status.html')
```

url.py

```
url(r'^test/status/$', 'status_page'),
```

jav.js

```
$('#start-form').on('submit',function(event){
event.preventDefault();    
status(); 
}); 
function status() { 
$.ajax({
    url : "status_page/", // the endpoint
    type : "POST", // http method
    data:{' ': '',}, // data sent with the post req
headers: {Accept: "application/json"},  
   success : function(json) {
//on success display the rendered page,so what coding is needed here?   
},
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
//error handling code    }
    });
 }
```

On execution the new page is not loaded, but if I bypass javascript then the form action gets executed and the new page rendering through the view happens. But with JavaScript, on success what happens ? how does the return statement from the view get captured in the success and how is the page displayed?
I need to use javascript and AJAX as once the new page is loaded I need to display continuous updates on the same page. So basically how do I implement redirection to a new page with the above code using javascript and Django? Any help will be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views.py, HttpResponseRedirect is used incorrectly. If you want to redirect to a new page, then you should use,

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/url-where-you-want-to-redirect/')
```

As `HttpResponseRedirect` expects url paramter instead of template name.

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect

Better approach would be to return a JSON response from your `status_page` view and then in `success` method of ajax, you can go to next URL:

```
window.location.href = '/url-where-you-want-to-redirect/';
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: ok ,for the first approach but where n how is the url parameter mapped to the actual template that gets loaded. will this again take you back to Url.py and then again to a view.
for the second approach , if I give the URL in javascript success, it again goes back to the url.py file to search for a matching view for that specific URL , this looks a loop where to load a URL you go the view then go back to javascript and then again get back to a view. Sorry m confused

Comment: I assume that in test.html page you are calling test/status/ via AJAX and when response comes, you redirect it to another URL. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: For first approach, you need to have another view and need to render another template from that view. This is the template which I believe will call some continuous updates on the submitted task as you mentioned.